# Getting wrong IP addresses

Tags: delphi, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to auto-detect and report on IPv6 availability for Delphi socket programming.

For "localhost", the following code is returning "1700::" for IPv6 and "2.0.0.0" for IPv4. This address is for simple testing, and should be returning ::1 or 127.0.0.1 for my machine. I'm not getting any socket API errors in the calling code, so I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong when attempting to convert "localhost" to the various IP addresses. I'm using Indy headers.

The type declarations are:

```
TLSocketAddress = record
  case Integer of
    AF_INET:
      (IPv4: TSockAddrIn);
    AF_INET6:
      (IPv6: TSockAddrIn6);
end;

TLIpInfo = record
private
  function GetFamily: TProtocolFamily;
public
  Address : TLSocketAddress;
  HostName: string;
  Machine: string;
  IP6 : string;
  IP4 : string;
  Port : integer;
  Error : integer;
  property Family : TProtocolFamily read GetFamily;
end;
```

and the retrieval routine is:

```
function GetIpInfo(
  const AHostName : string;
  const APort     : integer
  ): TLIpInfo;
var
  nameRet   : PAnsiChar;
  ptr       : Pointer;
  Hints     : TAddrInfoW;
  AddrInfo  : PAddrInfoW;
  NextInfo  : PAddrInfoW;
  RetVal    : Integer;
  ip,
  machine   : string;
  namelen   : integer;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Result, SizeOf(Result));
  FillChar(Hints, SizeOf(Hints), 0);
  Hints.ai_family := AF_UNSPEC;

  AddrInfo := nil;
  RetVal := GetAddrInfo(PWideChar(AHostName), nil, @Hints, @AddrInfo);
  if RetVal = 0 then
  try
    Result.HostName := AHostName;
    Result.Port := APort;
    NextInfo := AddrInfo;
    while NextInfo <> nil do
    begin
      if (NextInfo.ai_family = AF_INET) or (NextInfo.ai_family = AF_INET6) then
      begin
        if (Result.Machine = '') then
        begin
          SetLength(machine, NI_MAXHOST);
          RetVal := GetNameInfo(NextInfo.ai_addr, NextInfo.ai_addrlen,
            PChar(machine), NI_MAXHOST, nil, 0, 0);
          if (RetVal <> 0) then
          begin
            NextInfo := NextInfo.ai_next;
            continue;
          end;
          Result.Machine := PChar(machine);
        end;

        if NextInfo.ai_family = AF_INET then
        begin
          ptr := PSockAddrIn(NextInfo.ai_addr);
          namelen := INET_ADDRSTRLEN;
          SetLength(ip, namelen);
        end
        else
        begin
          ptr := PSockAddrIn6(NextInfo.ai_addr);
          namelen := INET6_ADDRSTRLEN;
          SetLength(ip, namelen);
        end;

        nameRet := inet_ntop(NextInfo.ai_family, ptr, PChar(ip), namelen);
        if (nameRet = nil) then
        begin
          NextInfo := NextInfo.ai_next;
          continue;
        end;

        if (NextInfo.ai_family = AF_INET6) then
          Result.IP6 := PChar(ip)
        else
          Result.IP4 := PChar(ip);
      end;
      NextInfo := NextInfo.ai_next;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAddrInfo(AddrInfo);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to lookup "localhost"? This can be set in `/etc/hosts`, DNS, etc.

Comment: Indeed, someone can set LocalHost to point to `8.8.8.8` if they wanted to

Comment: Also, if you are on a domain, you may be getting `localhost.example.com`, in which case, you can try `localhost.`.

Comment: This is generic local test code. Localhost is still defaulted, so these lookup values are not correct. Neither of these values are reachable for localhost, which IIUC should be ::1 or 127.0.0.1 by default, which is what they are on my machine.

Comment: You should not be using `getaddrinfo()` or any other DNS-based API to enumerate local IPs in the first place. They are unreliable and error-prone for local IPs. Use OS-specific enumeration APIs instead. Indy has a wrapper for that - the `TIdStack.AddLocalAddressesToList()` method. On Windows, it uses `GetAdaptersInfo()`/`GetAdaptersAddresses()`. On OSX/iOS, it use `getifaddrs()` (which may also be available on Linux and Posix systems). On other platforms, it still uses `getaddrinfo()`/`gethostbyname()` for the time being.

Comment: You can use `IPv4ToDWord()` and `MakeCanonicalIPv6Address()`, or the `TIdIPAddress` class, to detect if an IP address from `AddLocalAddressesToList()` is IPv4 or IPv6. In a future release, it will be updated with a new interface to report that information directly.

Comment: Try opening a command prompt and see what `ipconfig /all` actually reports, you will likely see `1700::` and `2.0.0.0` listed.  Your code is storing the last found IP of each type if there are multiple IPs present, and you are not checking if you have already stored an IP if another IP of the same type is found. Since you are doing a DNS lookup of `"localhost"`, you are not likely to actually see `::1` and `127.0.0.1` in the output from `getaddrinfo()` unless you have a loopback adapter installed.

Comment: Might it be that some 'internet security' software is modifying your results?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Remy, ipconfig /all reports neither 1700:: or 2.0.0.0 for any of the addresses displayed. This is a windows 8.1 box with Hyper-V enabled, so I have some virtual ethernet adapters being reported. However, I'll follow your hint about the indy addressing stuff to see if I can get what I'm expecting. It's tough wading through all the socket API info/calls to find what's best for xplat Delphi code, so I appreciate all your replies.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what I'm trying to do is initialize a socket object that will use IPv6 for the requested hostname if IPv6 is supported, and use IPv4 otherwise. I don't want the user to have to worry about whether it's IPv4 or IPv6. It looks like TIdStack.AddLocalAddressesToList() is for listing local addresses only. Again, my "localhost" test was just to have a "hostname" to lookup. When I use a machine name instead of localhost, I get the correct IPv4 but the IPv6 is still not correct afaict.

Comment: `TIdStack` has a `SupportsIPv6()` function to check if the local OS supports IPv6 sockets.  But to check a remote hostname for IPv6 support, you would have to do a DNS query, such as with `getaddrinfo()` or even `TIdDNSResolver`. I find it strange that `getaddrinfo(localhost)` would report `1700::` as an available IP unless either 1) you actually have that IP installed, or 2) your local machine's DNS configuration is corrupted.

Comment: If I use my local machine's name instead of localhost, I get 1700::FE80:0:0:0 which still isn't pingable (I know so little about IPv6 I'm not sure it should be), but I get that same IPv6 address for other machine names on my local network, so it looks like it's not specifically for my machine.

Comment: This sample code on MSDN shows an alterative method to determine if IPv6 is enabled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Remko thanks for the link. that looks like better msdn sample code than I was looking at before

Answer (score 1):

I know it may be too late for the author, but i struggled today with the same problem and noticed that you pass a pointer to the entire **ADDRINFO** structure to **inet_ntop**, however you should only be passing the pointer to the binary address.
So call to **intet_ntop** for **IPv4** addresses should be:

```
inet_ntop(NextInfo.ai_family, @PSockAddrIn(NextInfo.ai_addr).sin_addr, PChar(ip), namelen)
```

and for **IPv6** should be:

```
inet_ntop(NextInfo.ai_family, @PSockAddrIn6(NextInfo.ai_addr).sin6_addr, PChar(ip), namelen)
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! It's been a long time since I asked that, and it was resolved, but that code was done under a contract so I don't have access to it any more. You did great detective work -- I think I ended up noticing that same thing and correcting it.